# Do fully dressed use cases contain postconditions?

Tags: use-case

I am trying to solidify my understanding of the definition of a *fully dressed use case*.

I was asked a question in an interview which was as follows:

> Operations contracts are generally written for:
>
> 1. All fully dressed use cases
> 2. All use cases
> 3. The most complex operations in fully dressed use cases
> 4. The most elementary operations in brief use cases
> 5. None of the above

I chose `1. All fully dressed use cases` though I have a feeling I may be wrong.

Here is what I found after doing a little digging around,

As per the [Craig Larman PDF Page 7 and 8](https://www.craiglarman.com/wiki/downloads/applying_uml/larman-ch6-applying-evolutionary-use-cases.pdf)

I do not see Postconditions but then again I'm a little confused about the concept of a Fully dressed use case.

[image: part 1]

[image: part 2]

Comment: see [Why do interview questions make poor Software Engineering.SE questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260)

Comment: This is one of those poorly constructed (and quite arbitrary) interview questions - I think the answer should be (3), because operation contracts are used to supplement a description of some process, but it could also be (5), because strictly speaking use cases themselves describe flows in general terms, and don't have formal operations (you come up with those later) - and who the hell knows what the interview had in mind. BTW, how come you don't know if you got it correctly or not? Didn't they tell you the answer? Also, if you don't mind sharing, what position are you applying for?

Comment: @FilipMilovanović the question seems somewhat old-school but nevertheless tailored for a very specific purpose.  Hint:  an operation is not what it looks like.;-)

Comment: @Christophe It's not that I feel it's old-fashioned; I guess I'm just questioning the utility of the question. An experienced person who can do this sort of analysis doesn't necessarily have experience with this particular process, but can probably pick up the details along the way. On the other hand, a less experienced person may happen to know the answer (maybe they studied the approach from a book), but probably doesn't really understand how to apply any of this.

Comment: @Christophe Also, I understand your hint (and I've read your answer below), but what they'll accept as correct may depend on whether or not the person who created the interview questions considers writing operation contracts (that still can be defined on abstract design elements at this point) to be a part of use case elaboration. So because of this ambiguity it almost feels like a trick question to me.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I see your point.  if operational contracts are at class level, don't they belong to the solution space rather than the requirement space? Let me clarify why I qualified the interview as old-fashioned:  it seems to still be in a world of traditional detailed up-front use-cases, when half the world uses user-stories or story mapping,  when  popular UC authors have moved to use case 2.0 and incremental use-case slices, and the founding fathers of UML warned that step by step use-cases constrain UI design (and recommended essential use-cases to circumvent that flaw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not heard of the term "Fully Dressed" Use cases before, but Wikipedia suggests that the term refers to Alistair Cockburn's style of use cases.

You can also see his template on the Use Case page, which doesn't explicitly list "postconditions" or "operational contracts".

If we google a bit more we can find this quote from his book "writing effective use cases"

> ...And so there is no way this book
> can legislate for you just what quality measures you should adopt,
> beyond some fairly simple recommendations.

So the correct answer to the interview question is

6. None of the above, unless you have defined it in the template you made up for your project.

If it was a face to face interview you could name drop and mention the book, which your interviewer has obviously read, and then mention something you disagree with from it to show that you are in fact even more cleverer than the author.

As a multi-choice you are screwed.

I for one will be using "Fully Dressed" in future meetings, emails and answers I give on this site. People will be impressed and think I know the 'truth' about testing. But I wouldn't use it in an interview unless I am trying to show my boss that i am better than all the candidates, rather than actually hire people.

Comment: It did'nt dawn on me to ask the book name. I'll keep in mind the next time when such questions are asked.

Comment: Also I believe its related to Craig Larman's book the link for the PDf is given in the question

Comment: if you name drop be careful with the pronunciation

Comment: I believe the author's spelling is correct.

Comment: Ahh yes Craig! I'm not sure I agree with his views on.. checks notes.. functional requirements, but otherwise hes pretty solid.

Comment: I'm not clear how you reached the conclusion that "postconditions" or "operational contracts" aren't in fully dressed use cases. Both in Larmen's text linked in the question and Cockburn's Writing Effective Use Cases, the success guarantee is "what must be true on successful completion". I'm not sure how that's not a post condition.

Comment: @ThomasOwens - because Ewan's whole point was that this whole conception is arbitrary and that you don't have to use it, and that what you mean by these terms will vary from company to company. Thus the "unless you have defined it in the template *you made up* for your project" (*emphasis* mine). BTW, focusing on the title here is a bit misleading, as the interview question was about "operation contracts", which are not the same as use-case postconditions (or preconditions).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I don't agree. [Operations contracts](https://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~tinelli/classes/022/Spring15/Notes/chap11.pdf) are the combination of preconditions and postconditions. Depending on your use case template, these may be captured. Both Larman's and Cockburn's fully dressed use cases include both preconditions and postconditions, although they are called something else (success guarantees in both, but Cockburn also adds minimal guarantees). Even if the terms vary by company, there are well-regarded standards and conventions out there.

Comment: @ThomasOwens - yes, but not of the use case, it's pre/post-conditions of the operation. There are no formal operations in the usecase itself.

Comment: @ThomasOwens what Filip said, but also to me the structure of the question implies that the terms "operational contract" and "postcondition" should be explicitly mentioned OR not. I don't think you are free to interpret that kind of thing in a multi-choice QA. You would expect some source text that its referencing to exactly match the answer

Comment: In real life there is a whole bunch of stuff included in the suggested template that you could argue means the same thing, but it would be a weird way to ask the question.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion.  However the absence of post-condition in Cockburn's template is not sufficient to conclude: Bittner&Spence use a template with pre- and post-conditions ;-)

Comment: yes, presumably there is some source out there that uses all three terms and was the source for the question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the use case is defined. For Cockburn's fully dressed use case, then the postconditions are defined in the Minimal Guarantees and Success Guarantees sections of the use case. Others have created different structures which may not have sections explicitly for postconditions, but they could be captured in the description of the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

"Fully-dressed" is not an objective criteria in absence of an authoritative definition of what should be in a use-case specification.  For example, Cockburn and Bittner&Spence use a scenario/step approach,  whereas Constantine & Lockwood promote an intent based "[Essential use-case](http://www.mcs.vuw.ac.nz/research/object/Papers/euc-html/node4.html)", not to mention Jacobson&Bittner&Spence who now propose an agile [use-case 2.0](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook).

The trap of the recruitment question is in the UML terminology that is covertly used:

- An ***operation*** a unit of behavior (behavioral feature) of a classifier, i.e. what we colloquially call a method in many class-based programming languages.
- A ***contract*** is a set of constraints fulfilled by a classifier and its operations, e.g. preconditions, postconditions, invariants.
- As a consequence, an ***operational contract*** specifies how the internal operations of classes or components of the system should work.
- A ***use-case***, is a set of behaviors performed by the system with the actors, which yields an observable result of value for the actors. In other words, it describes something that can be observed from outside of the system, without knowing the internals of the system. The operational contracts are irrelevant in this context.
- The most elementary item in the specification of a use-case is a "***step***" or an "**intent**" depending on the specification strategy used.  It's not an ***operation***, which eliminates answers 3 and 4 of your test.

As a consequence, the only valid answer is "None of the above".

More generaly, while some popular use-case templates such as Cockburn's may propose no post-condition, others, like Bittner & Spence, have pre- and post-conditions. But these are about the system as a whole -- as observable by an actor -- and not about the hidden internals of individual operational contracts.